# TSQL - CASE to create two columns out of one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

For this simplified table structure (see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac0b8/6)) I need to get rid of the second row that is output for the same ID. It's possible that the row value is only "1" for a single ID.

```
    CREATE TABLE lookup 
    (
     id int, 
     field varchar(20), 
     row varchar(20),
     value varchar(50)
    );

INSERT INTO lookup
(id,field, row, value)
VALUES
(1,'55', '1', '1XYZ'),
(1,'55', '2', '2XYZ'),
(2,'55', '1', '3XYZ');


CREATE TABLE output 
    (
     id int, 
     value_1 varchar(50),
     value_2 varchar(50)
    );

INSERT INTO output
(id, value_1, value_2)
VALUES
(1, '1XYZ', '2XYZ'),
(2, '3XYZ', null);


-- wrong
select id
,case when (field = 55 and row = 1) then value END AS value_1
,case when (field = 55 and row = 2) then value END AS value_2
from lookup;
```

Hope you can show me how.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the number of rows always going to be 1 or 2 for the same id and field?
Could row = 3 and value = 4XYZ for id =1 and field = 55?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add aggregation to your query:

```
select id
,max(case when (field = 55 and row = 1) then value END) AS value_1
,max(case when (field = 55 and row = 2) then value END) AS value_2
from lookup
group by id;
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac0b8/8)

Comment: I would add the comment that this works because the `MAX` function ignores `NULL` values, and so effectively filters them out of each column, which is what the OP wants to achieve.

Comment: This looks good but my problem is how does this works with more columns in the select stmt? Do I need to put all columns in the group by stmt?

Comment: @TonyClifton Are the values of these extra columns the same per group, i.e. the same per `id`?

Comment: Yes, besides value_1 and value_2 all other values stay the same for a sinlge ID

Comment: @TonyClifton In this case you can add these values in the `GROUP BY` clause, so that you can select them.

Comment: a bit more type-work :-) but finally a correct output. Thank you!